# How do I convert language set notation to regular expressions?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have this following questing in regular expression and I just can't get my head around these kind of problems.

> L1 = { 0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>m</sup> | n≥3 ∧ m is odd }

How would I write a regular expression for this sort of problem when the alphabet is {0,1}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What's the answer?

The regular expression for your example is:

`000+1(11)*`<sup>1</sup>

So what does this do?

1. The first two characters, `00`, are literal zeros. This is going to be important for the next point
2. The second two characters, `0+`, mean "at least one zero, no upper bound". These first four characters satisfy the first condition, which is that we have at least three zeros.
3. The next character, `1`, is a literal one. Since we need to have an odd number of ones, this is the smallest number we're allowed to have
4. The last-but-one characters, `(11)`, represent a logical grouping of two literal ones, and the ending `*` says to match this grouping zero or more times. Since we always have at least one `1`, we'll always match an odd number. So we're done.

#### How'd I get that?

The key is knowing regular expression syntax. I happen to have quite a bit of experience in it, but [this](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) website helped me to verify.

Once you know the basic building blocks of regex, you need to break down your problem into what you can represent.

For example, regex allows us to specify a lower AND upper bound for matching (the `{x,y}` syntax), but doesn't allow to specify just a lower bound (`{x}` will match exactly `x` times). So I knew I would have to use either `+` or `*` to specify the zeros,  as those are the only specifiers that permit an infinite number of matches. I also knew that it didn't make sense to apply those modifiers to a group; the restriction that we must have at least 3 zeroes doesn't imply that we must have a multiple of three, for example, so `(000)+` was out. I had to apply the modifier to only one character, which meant I had to match a few literals first. `000` guarantees matching exactly three `0`s, and `0*` (Final expression `0000*`) does exactly what I want, and then I condensed that to the equivalent `000+`.

For the second condition, I had to think about what an odd number is. By definition, an odd number can be expressed by `2*k + 1`, where `k` is an integer. So I had to match one `1` (Hence the literal `1`), and some number of the substring `11`. That led me to the group, and then the `*`. On a slightly different problem, you could write `1(11)+` to match any odd number of ones, and at least 3.

---

<sup>1</sup> A colleague of mine pointed out to me that the `+` operator isn't technically part of the formal definition of regular expressions. If this is an academic question rather than a programming one, you might find the `0000*` version more helpful. In that case, the final string would be `0000*1(11)*`

Comment: The set notation is quite standard among the books I have read about automata theory.

Comment: @nhahtdh I've seen it quite extensively too, but I don't read much literature on formal definitions of binary strings, so I wasn't sure if it was universal or just a convention I'd been exposed to